# Does ordering matter when doing an insert?

Tags: mysql

For this query:

```
"INSERT INTO credentials (h_token, h_file, h_pass, email, name, picture, privacy) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
```

does the table structure matter in terms of the ordering of the column names.

Can `h_token`, `h_file`, etc. appear in any order?  By order I'm referring to what phpmyadmin displays, I assume there is some internal order as well.

I'm 90% they can, but I wanted to make sure.

Comment: they can appear in any order, as long as you follow the same order in the list of values.

Comment: don't follow, are you saying that the ? marks need to line up with the identifiers - h_token, f_file, etc. ?

Comment: the values that you provide that will be substituted for the question marks should be in the same order as the field names.

Comment: of course.  but in my table structure I can put the columns in any order, correct?

Answer (score 26):

If you're **not** specifying column names, then ordering matters (you must INSERT in the same order that the table is structured). If you **are** specifying the column names, the order doesn't matter.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME VALUES ('','','')
// Here the values needs to be in order of columns present in your table.

INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (ID, NAME, EMAIL) VALUES ('','','')`
// Here, ordering can be changed as per requirement.
```

Answer (score 2):

Columns can be specified in any order as long as they exist, but the values need to match your specified columns.